# unable to send Http headers through gSOAP

Tags: c++, wcf, http-headers, httprequest, gsoap

I'm consuming WCF service hosted from an App written in C#. I've written a C++ client accessing the service by means of gSOAP. I have to set headers and pass the same for a Service function. I tried following code but couldn't receive the headers at the C# server.

```
std::string ApiCode = "id: 111";
std::string PassCode = "code: abcd";
std::string httpHeader = std::string(ApiCode + " \r\n " + PassCode);

struct soap *soap = soap_new();
Request.soap = soap;
Request.soap->http_extra_header = httpHeader.data();

GetApiStatusProxy.GetAPIStatus(&Request, Response);
```

Please help me out.

Comment: It should look like this,
struct soap *soap = soap_new();
soap->http_extra_header = "head1: value1\r\nhead2: value2";
Please refer to the link.
https://www.genivia.com/tutorials.html#How_to_add_a_custom_HTTP_header

Comment: Use `httpHeader.c_str()`.